# Check if user has voted on a certain poll

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got a list of polls (questions), and would like to check if a certain `User` has voted on that certain poll. Here's my models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    has_answered = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Here's my view when a user votes on a poll:

```
def poll_answer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        answer = request.POST.get('answer')
        question = request.POST.get('question')

        q = Question.objects.get(question_text=question)

        choice = Choice.objects.get(id=answer)
        choice.votes += 1
        choice.save()
        ...
```

I've added a `ManyToMany` field in my `Question` model, which after reading the docs I believe is the right way to link the list of Users who have voted on a certain Question, but i'm not sure to be honest. The end goal is to put in my template something like: `if request.user in question.has_answered: don't display the poll`

How exactly would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, there are some logical and schematic issues that need to be addressed.

You are filtering questions based on a non-unique field `question_text` that is likely to return more than one object. You should either retrieve the question by `id`:

```
q = Question.objects.get(pk=question)
```

or make `question_text` field unique:

```
question_text = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
```

Second, incrementing `votes` by one via Python may lead to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) that might occur when two users want to increment votes at the same time. This is why there exists [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) objects in Django which lets you do the increment in database level:

```
from django.db.models import F

def poll_answer(request):
    ...
    choice = Choice.objects.get(id=answer)
    choice.votes = F("votes") + 1
    choice.save()
    ...
```

> I've got a list of polls (questions), and would like to check if a certain User has voted on that certain poll.

By your design, you **can't** because you are not storing who voted which question. You are just incrementing `votes` field when a user votes on a question.

One way to do that, you can change `votes` field to `ManyToManyField` and start storing users who have put a vote on a choice:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    votes = models.ManyToMany(User)
```

so you can check if a user has voted on a poll as follows:

```
has_voted = request.user.choice_set.filter(question=question).exists()
```

Furthermore, it seems to me that voting action here can act like an intermediate model between `Question` and `User` models so you might want to take a look at [how to define extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) section in Django docs.

If I were in your shoes, I would do something like below:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Vote")

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Vote(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that,
I would prefer to create another model for a vote:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='choices')
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    votes = models.ForgeinKey(Vote)
```

With that models you can count the number of votes easily: 
And you have the benefit of know what exactly user voted for in the question

```
Choice.objects.get(pk=PK).votes.count()
```

To detect if a user already voted:

```
if Vote.objects.filter(question=1, user=user_id).count() == 1
user_id voted for question 1 already
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `vote` view like this:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except:
        return render(request, 'your_question_page.html', {'question': question,
            'error_message': "Please select an option"})
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()

        return redirect('polls:result_page_view', question_id=question_id)
```

The above `vote` view will extract the option id of the chosen option but if there is an error like no option chosen then `except` block will execute and print the given error message otherwise it increases the vote count of the selected option by 1 and save it.
Hope this helps you.